# Month checkboxs

Tags: php

I have check box according to current month in my page, i have 1 (active) 0r 0 (inactive) value for them in database . I also have saved date corresponding to record. Now i want check box checked which values are 1 and corresponding to their date, and unchecked which values is 0. Other boxes should be empty because i have not not full month value.

```
   <?php 
            $isActiveYMD="";
            $isActive="";
            foreach($attendancelist as $attendancelis){
                $isActive[]= $attendancelis['EmployeeAttendance']['is_active'];
                $isActivee= $attendancelis['EmployeeAttendance']['date'];
                $isActiveYMD[] = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($isActivee));
            }
            $no_of_days= date("t");
            for($i=1;$i<=$no_of_days;$i++){
            ?>
            <div style="width:300px;float:left;">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="isactive" <?php if($isActive[$i]=="1"){ ?>checked="checked" <?php  }else{   } ?> />
            <?php echo $start = date(''.$i.'-m-Y'); ?>
            </br></br></br>     
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$isActiveYMD="";
$isActive="";
foreach($attendancelist as $attendancelis){
     $isActive[] = $attendancelis['EmployeeAttendance']['is_active'];
     $isActivee = $attendancelis['EmployeeAttendance']['date'];
     $isActiveYMD[] = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($isActivee));
}
for ($i=1;$i<=date('t');$i++) {
   echo '<div style="width:300px;float:left"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="';
   echo $unique_name; //this name is used to check if the checkbox is checkd in your form-action
   echo ($isActive[$i] == 1) ? '" checked="checked" /> ' : '" /> ';
   echo $i.date('-m-Y').'<br /><br /><br /></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I did not get you. Where to use $unique_name. I have value in array to show in boxs, but how to set it in correct box

Comment: each checkbox needs an unique name, so when you submit the form you can check the value. you cant/shouldnt have multiple checkboxes with the same name. If i.e. i have a checkbox named "smth" i can check if its checked or not, like this: if ($_POST['smth'] == 1)